# What is the shape of the magnetic field of a bar magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was wondering if there was a brief but precise description of the shape of the magnetic field that a bar magnet produces. I can’t seem to find much other than the basic “field lines go out one end and come back to the other”.

Comment: Get a bar magnet, set it on a table, place a sheet of heavy paper or thin posterboard on top, and then sprinkle iron filings on top of that.

Comment: I would say 'toroidal'.

Answer (score 9):

I have students in the second semester introductory class map the field of bar magnets by hand using miniature compasses as probes. The thing that surprises them is when I ask them to compare maps between groups: there isn't a "the shape of the field" because a typical bar magnet is anything but ideal.

They are predominately dipoles, but there is little that can be said beyond that.

Comment: Right - once you are a reasonable distance (d>>L) away, the dipole approximation is very good. Closer, there is not much you can say.